# Angular2 http call and typified Observable problems

Tags: json, http, angular, asp.net-web-api, observable

I've been trying to use Observables with Angular2 for an http call to a Web Api for quite a while now but couldn't find a working solution. The json data which I want to retrieve from the web service (a list of levels with properties for each level) should be converted afterwards by the help of a class definition for level and then shown as a simple list on my view.
I found and tried out lots of examples, but they are either referring to elder versions, not complete or too complicated to understand the basic principle behind this workflow in angular. Could you please give me an easy, complete and up-to-date example? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: https://gist.github.com/btroncone/d6cf141d6f2c00dc6b35 this might help

Comment: Here're a couple of nice examples (in my opinion): http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/angular2/3577/angular-2-rxjs-subjects-and-observables-with-api-requests

Comment: When you cannot understand something, you should into its definition : http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html

There are plenty of examples on SO, and on plunkrs

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but I asked for an easy, working example for one special case (api call) and hoped for a good explanation beneath. I know that google is open for everyone and I was searching there for two days and trying around. But I must admit that at least the first two links weren't that bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since my earlier update actually is the momentary solution for me, I'm posting it now as a solution. Believe me or not, it was hard work of three days to only partially understand how Observables work in my case and what is really important, correct and up-to-date with the tons of variations one can find online.

This happens in my base service (I have levels, badges, ... as achievements and want to reuse get/ post/ put/ delete):

```
getAllAchievements(detailPath): Observable<Response> {
// prepare request url and header
this.specificUrl = this.webServiceUrl + detailPath;
this.headers.append('Content-type', 'application/json');
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers });
this.result = this.http.get(this.specificUrl, options)
.catch(error => this.handleError(error));
return this.result;}
```

This happens in my level service (here, I call the base service):

`observable : Observable<Response>; 
getAllLevels(): Observable<Level[]> {
    this.observable = this.achievementsService.getAllAchievements(this.allLevelsUrlPart);
    return this.observable
    .map((response: Response) => {
      const srcData = response.json() as Level[];
      return srcData;})
    .catch(error => this.handleError(error));}`
This happens in my controller:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.levelsObservable = this.levelsService.getAllLevels();
            this.levelsObservable.subscribe(
              data => console.log(data)
        );
  }
```

and the view code looks like this:

```
<label *ngFor="let level of levelsObservable | async">{{level}}</label>
```

the Level class looks like this:

```
export class Level {
    constructor(
        public id: number, 
        public name: string, 
        public description: string
        ){}}
```

The "data" output on the console is: "Array[Array[4]]" and the view shows:
"[Object object], [Object object], [Object object], [Object object]". 
On debugging, I see that the objects really contain the data from the request, but it looks as if they weren't converted correctly into levels.

Even on the [Official Angular 2 page](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html)

when checking the example url in detail, one can see that they have this Object array and work with it. So it looks like we have to live with it - 
Except one has a better solution for it.